# Como mudar o idioma do conteúdo de uma aplicação com Cordova de português para inglês?

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache-cordova

Tenho uma aplicação feita em HTML, CSS e Javascript usando o Apache Cordova, ela tem suporte a inglês e português, porem como faço pra mudar o conteúdo de todas as páginas dela quando a pessoa seleciona inglês ou português em uma página de configurações?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode identificar o idioma do usuário do seu aplicativo usando o [Plugin Globalization](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization)

> https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization

Depois de identificar o idioma que está no aparelho do seu usuário, você direciona ele para a pagina certa de acordo com o idioma que ele usa, ou muda todo o idioma do aplicativo com o javascript. ( Fica a sua escolha )